# Jinja2 template host groups conditions

Tags: templates, jinja2, host

I have the following condition in a Jinja2 template for a configuration file
It works fine but... not completely...

```
"name" : "{% set hosts = groups['APP-PTC-B'] %}{% if hosts is defined %}CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-B{% else %}CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-A{% endif %}",
```

This template is executed for two nodes found in groups APP-PTC-A and APP-PTC-B.
I was expecting that if the template, being executed on B node group would define one name and everything else would receive another name.

each host group is defined in the "deploy.yml" playbook

I'm not getting at why it is not working as expected. A node host and B node host receives "CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-B" as name and not per each host.

Could you lease see what i'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

But your code is looking at group APP-PTC-B, if hosts is defined it will have CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-B else CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-A.

host is always defined hence it always have the CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-B name.
You may want to use something that only belongs to APP-PTC-B group, something like:

```
{% if SOMENAME in APP-PTC-B %}CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-B{% else %}CONSUMER.GROUP.NODE-A{% endif %}
```

The code is not for straight copy paste, check the syntax. SOMENAME should be unique